# How to get a value for a particular number in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following file

```
Build-value 
123-67
145-69
```

I want a bash script to get the value for a specific build number. For example, I want it to get the value for build number 145 (value is 69)

How can I do this in bash? The bash script needs to be able to get the value for any specified build number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one liner-

```
grep -w "^145" file.txt | awk -F "-" '{print $2}'
```

Change 145 to whatever you want to find the corresponding value for.

Better to do it with just awk-

```
awk -F "-" '/^145/ {print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: Note that this will also match `1145-xx` and `xx-145` occurrences for build number `145`. It will also output multiple results if multiple matches are found. As a suggestion, you should use `"^145-"` as the first argument of `grep` as well as the flag `-m 1` to stop after the first match.

Comment: Thanks @pah. Edited it to avoid mismatches. I would advise against using grep -m in such cases because then you're assuming that the first match is the 'correct' match. A better thing to do is to figure out why there are more than one matches in the first place. Which you already did. I hope the edited version satisfies you. Thanks

Comment: There's no need to use `grep` with `awk`; `awk` already knows how to match its input.

Comment: @chepner, very belated but I incorporated your suggestion. Of course you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Use bash builtin regular expressions.

Contents of `build_value.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ${#} -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0} <build file> <build number>"
    exit 1
fi

build="${2}" # This is the build number
file="${1}"  # This is the build file
contents=$(<"${file}")

if [[ " ${contents//$'\n'/ }" =~ \ ${build}-([0-9]+) ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; # this will echo the build value
fi
```

Contents of `builds.txt`:

```
123-67
145-69
```

Usage:

```
$ ./build_value.sh builds.txt 145
```

Output:

```
69
```

Note:

- <s>I'm assuming the format for build numbers and values are all in one line (as stated in the question).</s> (See EDIT section).
- This will match any occurrence of, in this case, `145-<digits>`, so I'm assuming that build numbers are unique, otherwise only the first occurrence will match.

**EDIT:**

- Now with newline support (or in this case, substitution).

Comment: If you looked at the text in the question, the `Build-value`, `123-67` and `145-69` were all on separate lines.  Especially when 'data' is not formatted, it is worth looking at the question to check what the OP wants.  I indented the material in the question.  (And yes, the OP should know better by now.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fixed. Yeah I should have done that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex's [look-behind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Example with `grep` with [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) activated (`-P`):

```
get_value() {
    build=${1:?You should provide a build number}
    grep -Po "(?<=$build-)[0-9]+" builds.txt
}
```

---

#### Example

```
$ cat builds.txt 
123-67
145-69
$ get_value 145
69
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F- -v build=145 '$1 == build {print $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed`:

```
build=145; sed -n "s/^${build}-\([0-9]*\)/\1/p" file
```

This is a `sed` substitution extract the number after the `-` matching the value of the `build` variable.